# Jenkins pipeline install and use yarn

Tags: docker, jenkins, yarnpkg

I am installing the `yarn` package in as a global in an early `stage`.

```
+ npm i yarn -g
/usr/local/bin/yarnpkg -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/usr/local/bin/yarn -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
+ yarn@1.7.0
added 1 package in 1.376s
```

The use of the package is giving me an error.

> yarn: Permission denied

```
+ yarn install --prefer-offline
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/abide@tmp/durable-3cf966e5/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/abide@tmp/durable-3cf966e5/script.sh: yarn: Permission denied
```

The pipeline begins with

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node'
            args '-u root:root'
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: probably not an explanation, but it *might* be that yarn is (for some reason) not ready yet. I got the same issue and I found adding a small pause help to avoid that. Hope it helps...

Comment: did you ever resolve this?